# Google Firebase Web Application Login Page

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I have an `index.html` page which is the landing page of my Google Firebase Hosted Web application.

On this page I have boxes for `username` and `password` as well as a `LOGIN` button.

I want the `LOGIN` button to redirect my user to the `home.html` page if their username and password are authenticated on my Google Firebase Authentication list. If they are not a valid user a message must pop up saying "Contact Admin for login credentials"

I can't find help of this issue in any of the Google Firebase Documentation...

Comment: "*I can't find help of this issue in any of the Google Firebase Documentation...*" There's an entire section in the Firebase documentation dedicated to [Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) - is this not what you're looking for?

Comment: Hey Jillian. That sounds like a fairly standard requirement for a web site logging in with Firebase, and should follow the basics from the documentation on [getting started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) pretty closely. Did you try anything already? What is the exact part that you're struggling with?

Comment: I think you just need to do something like this.
Add an event listener on login button and add authentication code there. if they are authenticated you can use window.location method to redirect them on home.html otherwise just show an alert in else about contacting the admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those also looking, I came right by using the below github file as a refernce/starting point.

[https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/email-password.html][1]